# Enabling Oracle jdbc driver logs on Websphere 6.1

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, websphere-6.1

I am having some problems with an Hibernate Criteria query causing a outOfIndex error at driver level, I am pretty sure the problem is at the driver as I have being debugging and everything seems ok, but to be sure and be able to report the error I need to enable traces and I am not being able to do so.

I have added ojsbc5_g.jar as a new JDBC provider and created a new data source with it, renamed the jndi of the old one so the new debug data source uses the same and tried using `-Doracle.jdbc.Trace=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=ConfigFile.properties`
at the server JVM configuration (using a absolute path for the file and a relative one).

The data source and the app works but no log appears, then I found the data source custom properties so I modified the level and the filename and now the file is there but empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JVM Configuration should include:

```
-Doracle.jdbc.Trace=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/jdbc/OracleLog.properties
```

and the mentioned properties file should include something like:

```
.level=SEVERE
oracle.jdbc.level=ALL
oracle.jdbc.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

You can set the logging for following targets depending on the nature of your problem:

```
oracle.jdbc
oracle.jdbc.driver
oracle.jdbc.pool
oracle.jdbc.rowset
oracle.jdbc.xa
oracle.sql
```